# Print function doesn't terminate

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't know why PrintList() doesn't terminate. It is a LinkedList, so when I go to next, that should terminate. 
When I do AddNode once and then print, that terminates, when I do addNode twice, print doesn't terminate.

The reason why in constructor I create 5 empty spots is because I'm required to create those 5 empty spots when program starts.

Moreover, if for example I add twice , how I can assign pointer to that second value?

```
#pragma once
class LinkedList
{
private:
    typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr n;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
public:
    LinkedList();
    void AddNode(int addData);
    void PrintList();
    ~LinkedList();
};

#include "LinkedList.h"
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;

    n = new node;

    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
        //cout << n<<endl;
        n->next = n;
    }

}

void LinkedList::AddNode(int addData) {
    //nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;
    cout << n <<endl;
    if (head != NULL) {
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}


void LinkedList::PrintList() {
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

}


LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    delete n;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    LinkedList *l = new LinkedList();
    l->AddNode(5);
    l->AddNode(8);
    l->PrintList();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `AddNode` function is very, very wrong. If you call it twice, your list then consists of a single node that points to itself.

Comment: @Beta , I understand that it is wrong, but don't see why, could you please elaborate on that? And how that can be fixed?

Comment: Try stepping through it with pencil and paper (as if you were the computer, executing the program). After the first call, there is one node, call it **X**, `n` and `head` both point to it, and X.next=NULL. On the second call you do not create a new node, you overwrite the data in X, you set `curr` to point to X, then you set X.next to point to X.

Answer (score 0):

The node n is always the same since you are not setting n to a different node
So when you do n->next and n->data , the same node is being modified each time

> ```
> void LinkedList::AddNode(int addData) {
>     //nodePtr n = new node; // you need to uncomment this
>     n->next = NULL;
>     n->data = addData;
>     cout << n <<endl;
>     if (head != NULL) {
>         curr = head;
>         while (curr->next != NULL) {
>             curr = curr->next;
>         }
>         curr->next = n;
>     }
>     else {
>         head = n;
>     }
> }
>
>
> After your first addNode(5), lets examine the values.
> head = n
> head->data = 5
> head->next = null
>
> After your second addNode(8)
> head = n
> head->data = 8
> head->next = n // set by "curr->next = n" .
> ```

So you have a problem here. When you try to loop through your linked list, it will become head->next->head->next->head->next->head->next ..... causing an infinite loop